# How To Bind External Files To Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to open a file in AWS Lambda. Lambda is reads that file and process. But I am having a problem with it. I researched for a day and I am suspected that I need to write webpack config. I am not sure its related or not.

File Structure

```
--root--
--cdk
----index.ts
--src
----index.js
----template.htm
----lambda.js
```

I have NodeJSFunction in **index.ts**

```
     const commLambda = new NodejsFunction(this, 'Service_CommunicationForm', {
        runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
        entry: './src/index.js',
        handler: 'handler',
        memorySize: 128,
        role,
        bundling: {
            minify: true,
            //target: 'es2020',
            sourceMap: true
        }
    });
```

Inside of index.js im calling lambda.handler

```
const middy = require('@middy/core');
const ssm = require('@middy/ssm');
const bodyParser = require('@middy/http-json-body-parser');
const validationMiddleware = require('./middleware/validation');
const { handler: mailHandler } = require('./lambda');

const middyConfig = {
  cache: true,
  paths: {
    SSM: process.env.SSM_PREFIX,
  },
};

module.exports.handler = middy(mailHandler)
  .use(ssm(middyConfig))
  .use(bodyParser())
  .use(validationMiddleware())
```

## HANDLER

```
module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
  .
  .
  const template = path.join(__dirname, './src/communicationTemplate.htm');
  .
  .
};
```

When I send a request, I am having this error

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "errno": -2,
        "code": "ENOENT",
        "syscall": "open",
        "path": "/var/task/src/communicationTemplate.htm"
    }
}
```

So I decided to print whats inside /var/task/

```
[ './index.js', './index.js.map', './original_lambda_archive.zip' ]
```

I think this is explains why im having ENOENT. There is no file called template.htm. I should bind it somehow. Do you have any idea?

I am using cdklocal to deploy it and using localstack for mocking AWS

Thanks.

Comment: What's the connection between `communicationTemplate.htm` and `template.htm`?

Comment: Same my mistake